The $\text{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$-modules for some finite dimensional vector space $V$ and field $\mathbb{F}$ are just direct sums of $V$.
I've been stuck on this question for a while now. Firstly, I was trying to solve this directly. In the finite dimensional case for $M$, I was trying to show that the only possible simple module is $V$, and then break it down inductively. However, I couldn't make much progress on this, let alone when $M$ is not infinite dimensional.
There was one other question we have (which I haven't solved yet) that is to show that for some algebra $A$ and an $A$-module $M$, $M$ is simple if and only if the $eAe$-module $eM$ is simple.
Given this, for finite dimensional $M$, we let $\text{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V) = M_n(\mathbb{F})$, and let $e$ be the matrix with $1$ in its top left entry and $0$'s elsewhere. With this setup and the above statement, we have that $eV \cong \mathbb{F}$ as it just isolates the first component of a vector. This must be a simple module as it is just a one-dimensional vector space. So we just need to prove that if $eM$ is a simple $eM_n(\mathbb{F})e$-module that $M \cong V$, at least for the finite dimensional case.
For this, first note that by some algebra, $eAe$ just isolates the top left element of any matrix $A$, so $eM_n(\mathbb{F})e \cong \mathbb{F}$. So notably the only simple $\mathbb{F}$-module is $\mathbb{F}$ itself. So we have $eM$ is a one-dimensional vector space under the assumption that it is simple. Let $eM = \text{span}\{v\}$.
That's where I got stuck. I was thinking of then letting $e_i$ in general be the matrix where the $i$th entry on the diagonal is $1$ and all else is $0$, and doing this we get $n$ different linearly independent vectors such that $e_i v_j = \delta_{ij} v_j$ using idempotence. However, I saw no way to find the action of the entire algebra on the $v_j$.
Moreover, I haven't even proven the statement I'm trying to use. Does anyone have any hints to try and push me in the right direction?

Try decomposing $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ as a module for itself.

Hmm, so I've seen that this is just equal to $V^n$ as each of the columns can be identified with one copy of $V$. But I didn't see how I could apply that to a general $M$?

Well any simple left module of an algebra $A$ will be a quotient of the left regular  representation of $A$ on itself (pick a non-zero element $v \in M$ and send $a \to av$). So if you verify that $V$ is simple, then decomposition of $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ into $n$ copies of $V$ means it must be the only simple module.

Oh! That makes sense, that seems like an important result but I don't think I've seen that yet! Thanks so much, that's a great solution.
